# How to send postMessage to iframe from parent page

Tags: javascript, postmessage

I'm trying to send a message to iframe from the page, but it seems like this message does not received.
Code from the page:

```
let iframe = document.getElementById('myiframe')
iframe.contentWindow.postMessage('message body', window.location.origin)
console.log('message sent')
```

Code from the iframe:

```
window.addEventListener('message', function(m){
  console.log(m)
}, false)
```

So, in the console I see only the first part - '*message sent*', what can be the reason of this issue? Site and iframe have different domains

Comment: Add `console.log("blah")` after your code in `iframe` to make sure it's actually executed. It will also tell you if it's loaded AFTER message was sent or not. Also, you might need use `postMessage` from inside `onload` event (?)

Comment: If you have two different domains then `window.location.origin` isn't the origin of the iframe page. Origin needs to match the page in the iframe. Also, the `console.log('message sent')` statement will always run whether the message was sent or not.

Comment: Thanks, @zer00ne - I've changed window.location.origin to iframe's domain url and it works